# Javascript, Merging two sorted arrays: Can someone please tell me why this isn't giving the correct mergeSort?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mergesort

I've tried merging the two arrays but the output i get is [ 0, 3, 3, 4, 4 ]

```js
function mergeSortedArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var arr3 = [];

  if (arr1 === undefined || arr1.length == 0) {
    return arr2;
  }

  if (arr2 === undefined || arr2.length == 0) {
    return arr1;
  }

  while (i < arr1.length - 1 && j < arr2.length - 1) {
    if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
      arr3.push(arr1[i]);
      i++;
    } else {
      arr3.push(arr2[j]);
      j++;
    }
  }
  return arr3;
}

console.log(mergeSortedArrays([0, 3, 4, 31], [3, 4, 6, 30]));
```

For this example, i know i haven't accounted for the case in which arrays are of different size but that is for a later problem. The code currently isn't even working for the basic case. It does not iterate all the way through and breaks midway. Can someone please address this problem. I've worked around with the while loop but the code still doesnt work.

Comment: Which output do you want to get?

Comment: @P4uB0rd4 this is a merge sort, so `[0, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 30, 31]`

Answer (score 1):

You are making two mistakes.

- In the `while` loop condition check of `length` of array not `length - 1`. This will not add last elements of both array.
- Your while loop will end when one of the array will be completely loop because of `&&`. So after while add the remaining elements of other array.

```js
function mergeSortedArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var arr3 = [];

  if (arr1 === undefined || arr1.length == 0) {
    return arr2;
  }

  if (arr2 === undefined || arr2.length == 0) {
    return arr1;
  }

  while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
    if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
      arr3.push(arr1[i]);
      i++;
    } else {
      arr3.push(arr2[j]);
      j++;
    }
    
  }
  if(i === arr1.length){
      return arr3.concat(arr2.slice(j))
    }
    else if(j === arr2.length){
      return arr3.concat(arr1.slice(i))
    }
}

console.log(mergeSortedArrays([0, 3, 4, 31], [3, 4, 6, 30]));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the loop needs to iterate till arr1.lenght and arr2.lenght not till lenght - 1,

```
while (i < arr1.length  && j < arr2.length )
```

Also, after the loop breaks, the reason being either one of the array loop variables has a false condition, before returning the array, you need to check if there are values left which are not yet inserted. **This is important**.

You can do this:

```
arr3.concat(arr1.slice(i)).concat(arr2.slice(j));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things missing in your code:

1. The while loop is running for `i < arr1.length - 1` for `arr1` and `j < arr2.length - 1` for `arr2`. That means it will run till 3rd index of arr1 and arr2. So the last index will not be executed in the loop. So you should refactor the loop as `i < arr1.length` for `arr1` and `j < arr2.length` for `arr2`.
2. Next missing thing, you need to add the loop for remaining elements of remaining array. That means when you execute the code then all the elements of one loop will be pushed in the `arr3` then one elements of another array will be missed and it will not be pushed in the `arr3` (for same length of both array) and/or more than one elements of another array will be missed (for different length of both array). So you need to push the remaining elements of another array to the `arr3`.

I have added the refactored code of your code.

```
function mergeSortedArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var arr3 = [];

    if (arr1 === undefined || arr1.length == 0) {
        return arr2;
    }

    if (arr2 === undefined || arr2.length == 0) {
        return arr1;
    }

    while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
            arr3.push(arr1[i]);
            i++;
        } else {
            arr3.push(arr2[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i < arr1.length) {
        arr3.push(arr1[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while (j < arr2.length) {
        arr3.push(arr2[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return arr3;
}
```

`OR`

you can use spread operator to merge both array and then you can use sort method of JS.

```
function mergeTwo(arr1, arr2) {
  let result = [...arr1, ...arr2];
  return result.sort((a,b) => a-b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple one line solutions that does involve a resort. Using default parameters to deal with undefined arrays, and the spread operator to populate a new array with the two merging arrays. The result array just needs to be sorted and then returned.

```
const mergeSorted = (a1 = [], a2 = []) => [...a1, ...a2].sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

### Example

```js
const mergeSorted= (a1 = [], a2 = []) => [...a1, ...a2].sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(mergeSorted([0, 3, 4, 31], [3, 4, 6, 30]).join(", "));
```

Or without the sort and using parameter defaults to avoid needing to test arrays for undefined

```
function mergeSorted(a1 = [], a2 = []) {
    const res = [];
    var idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0;
    while (idx1 < a1.length || idx2 < a2.length) {
        if (idx1 < a1.length && idx2 < a2.length) {
           res.push(a1[idx1] < a2[idx2] ? a1[idx1++] : a2[idx2++]);
        } else {
           res.push(idx1 < a1.length ? a1[idx1++] : a2[idx2++]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

### Example

```js
function mergeSorted(a1 = [], a2 = []) {
    const res = [], l1 = a1.length, l2 = a2.length;
    var i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    while (i1 < l1 || i2 < l2) {
        if (i1 < l1 && i2 < l2) { res.push(a1[i1] < a2[i2] ? a1[i1++] : a2[i2++]) }
        else { res.push(i1 < l1 ? a1[i1++] : a2[i2++]) }
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(mergeSorted([0, 3, 4, 31, 99], [3, 4, 6, 30]).join(", "));
```

Answer (score -1):

In the while condition when i or j indexes reach the length of the corresponding array finishes the loop returning an array of the lower length.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
function mergeTwoSortedArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  let merged = [];
  let index1 = 0;
  let index2 = 0;
  let current = 0;

  while (current < (arr1.length + arr2.length)) {

    let isArr1Depleted = index1 >= arr1.length;
    let isArr2Depleted = index2 >= arr2.length;

    if (!isArr1Depleted && (isArr2Depleted || (arr1[index1] < arr2[index2]))) {
      merged[current] = arr1[index1];
      index1++;
    } else {
      merged[current] = arr2[index2];
      index2++;
    }

    current++;
  }

  return merged;
}
```

Fore more info : https://wsvincent.com/javascript-merge-two-sorted-arrays/

Comment: You shouldn't copy and paste the code in your answer. Try to write and debug the code your self and also explain the mistake in code and its solution.